# Python : How to increment element in a For loop of a list of strings?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and while I was looking at a course, I had an idea of something I'm not finding a solution for :

```
proteins = ["venison", "tuna", "chicken"]
veggies = ["kale", "spinach", "tomatoes"]

for i in proteins:
    for j in veggies:
        if j == "spinach":
            print("Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog")
    print(i,j)
print(type(j))
```

Result :

```
venison kale
Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog
venison spinach
venison tomatoes
tuna kale
Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog
tuna spinach
tuna tomatoes
chicken kale
Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog
chicken spinach
chicken tomatoes
```

My intent is to, instead of printing "Venison Spinach..." and meat and spinach, really, is to have the sentence ("Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog") instead of printing the "menu".

The idea I have is then,
Whenever `j==spinach` we
`print("Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog")`
and here we go to the next index before
`print(i,j)`.

How can I do this?

Hope my question makes sense!
Thank you,

Comment: Did you copy your indentation correctly? I don't get the same output you show.

Comment: I get that output if `print(i, j)` is indented another level.

Comment: Could you describe your desired output?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `else` in addition to `if`, like this:

```
proteins = ["venison", "tuna", "chicken"]
veggies = ["kale", "spinach", "tomatoes"]

for i in proteins:
    for j in veggies:
        if j == "spinach":
            print("Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog")
        else:
            print(i,j)
print(type(j))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if j == 'Spinach':
  print(...)
  continue
```

OR

```
if j == 'Spinach':
   print("Feed it..")
else:
   print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proteins = ["venison", "tuna", "chicken"]
veggies = ["kale", "spinach", "tomatoes"]

for i in proteins:
    for j in veggies:
        if j == "spinach":
            print("Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog")
        else:
            print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha... as simple as else... Dumb me ^^'
Why make easy when you can make complicated?

That being said, would there be a way to increment the index or element in some ways?

I tried

```
proteins = ["venison", "tuna", "chicken"]
veggies = ["kale", "spinach", "tomatoes"]

for i in proteins:
    for j in veggies:
        if j == "spinach":
            print("Spinach?!? Feed it to the dog")
            j=j+1
        print (I,j)
```

But it returns an error :
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.

I understand I or j are not indexes of the list... so I wonder how I can do it.

Thank you everyone!